# Javadocs getting added everywhere

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I use Javadocs to add descriptions to my methods. In Eclipse I just place the mouse over the method name and click on the Add Javadoc menu. Sometimes though I notice it adds a bunch of empty comments to every field and method in my file. This is really annoying and I have no idea why it does this. Am I doing something inadvertently or is this a bug in the Javadocs plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can define how you want the code template to look. In Eclipse, go to: Window -> preferences. There look up Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates. Then you can define what the javadoc should look like, or not look like.

Comment: How they look wasn't my question. It's adding comments everywhere. I only asked it to put a comment on the method I selected. This normally works but occasionally it puts them on all fields.